Django ORM: Use an annotation's alias in subsequent annotations
I want to reuse an annotation's alias in subsequent expressions. How can I make Django generate SQL like the following:
select
    a*b as x
    x/d as y
from my_table;

Note how x is simply referenced in x/d, rather than being expanded into (a*b)/d. Is this possible in Django?
The reason I want to do this is because my queries are very large and complex. When using regular annotations, Django is duplicating large expressions many times and the resulting query output is becoming overly complex and difficult to debug and ensure correctness.

Well, I must be misunderstanding something, but what makes you feel like you can do that? I even started questioning my consciousness, went to psql (16.3) to check, and no, select 1 as x, 2*x as y; isn't valid and produces ERROR:  column "x" does not exist. So that doesn't work for all DBMSs supported by Django, isn't a performance or expressiveness improvement, and thus is very unlikely to be implemented in Django ORM.

SQLite and MariaDB also reject that. Is it supported by any DBMS at all?..

Hmmm interesting, it works in Clickhouse which is the DB I'm using. I didn't realize it was nonstandard

Chaining aliases isn't a part of the SQL spec, because aliases aren't evaluated until the end of the expression. So at the time of alias creation, x/d isn't valid syntax because x hasn't been defined yet. But you can do it using subqueries or a CTE, as x would then be defined in the first query and then be available for consumption in the subsequent queries. However, it's not immediately clear to me that this would fulfill the goal of reducing verbosity, since it means having to stack even more subqueries. I'm not sure how you would do it in Django ORM either.

How about this way?
from django.db.models import F

class TestListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Test.objects.annotate(x=F('a') * F('b'), y=F('x') / F('d'))
    ...

If you convert the above query, it is as below.
SELECT "test_test"."id", "test_test"."a", "test_test"."b", "test_test"."d", 
("test_test"."a" * "test_test"."b") AS "x", 
(("test_test"."a" * "test_test"."b") / "test_test"."d") AS "y" 
FROM "test_test"

